# d3.js concentric ring chart

Tags: javascript, charts, d3.js

I am looking to develop an arc ring chart. Where each new set of data is displayed as a concentric ring inside the other.

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/101/

I've tried to take a sum of the values in the data, and use this to help develop a proportion algorithm, to ensure each arc never does more than one cycle.

this part manages the concentric ring.

```
getArc: function(){
            var that = this;

            var radiusArray = [100, 80];

            function getRadiusRing(i){
                return that.radius-(i*20);              
            }
            var thickness = 15;

            var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                    .innerRadius(function(d){
                        return getRadiusRing(d.index);                      
                    })
                    .outerRadius(function(d){
                        return getRadiusRing(d.index)+thickness;    
                    })
                    .startAngle(function(d, i){
                        return d.startAngle;
                    })
                    .endAngle(function(d, i){
                        return d.endAngle;
                    });     
            return arc;
        }
```

but I think there is a flaw in the end angle calculations. If you enable more data - the concentric rings although they form correctly have suspicious arc lengths where they wrap around the entire chart?

```
setData: function(data){
            var diameter = 2 * Math.PI * this.radius;           
            var localData = new Array();

            var segmentValueSum = 0;
            $.each(data[0].segments, function( ri, va) {
                segmentValueSum+= va.value;
            });

            $.each(data[0].segments, function(ri, value) {

                var segmentValue = value.value;

                var fraction = segmentValue/segmentValueSum;

                var arcBatchLength = fraction*2*Math.PI;
                var arcPartition = arcBatchLength;      

                var startAngle = 0;
                var endAngle = ((ri+1)*arcPartition);               

                data[0].segments[ri]["startAngle"] = startAngle;
                data[0].segments[ri]["endAngle"] = endAngle;
                data[0].segments[ri]["index"] = ri;
            });

            localData.push(data[0].segments);

            return localData[0];        
        }
```

---

trying to build the chart to look like the following

[image: Concentric ring chart]

I've enhanced the chart, but still have issues with the placement and updating of the legend, rings and values. Why is old data remaining?
http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/123/

if there is more or less data - the labels don't get placed correctly

```
 //draw labels                      
            valueLabels = value_group.selectAll("text.value").data(reversedata)
            valueLabels.enter().append("svg:text")
            .attr("class", "value")
            .attr("transform", function(d) {
                var rings = counts;

                return "translate("+(that.radius+55)/rings+", 0)";
            })
             .attr("dx", function(d, i){
                return 19*i;            })
            .attr("dy", function(d, i){
                return -5;
            })
            .attr("text-anchor", function(d){
                return "start";
            }).text(function(d){
                return d.value;
            });

            valueLabels.transition().duration(300).attrTween("d", arcTween)
            valueLabels.exit().remove();
```

Comment: A related discussion: [Concentric arcs using D3.js](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24507751/320399)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to fix all the bugs - Here is the final code as a jquery plugin, enjoy

[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/165/

```
$(document).ready(function() {


            (function( $ ){
                var methods = {
                    el: "",
                    init : function(options) {
                        var clone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, options["data"]);
                        var preparedData = methods.setData(clone);

                        methods.el = this;          
                        methods.setup(preparedData, options["width"], options["height"]);
                    },
                    setup: function(data, w, h){

                        var selector = methods.el["selector"];

                        var padding = 20;


                        var chart = d3.select(selector).append("svg:svg")
                            .attr("class", "chart")
                            .attr("width", w)
                            .attr("height", h)
                        .append("svg:g")
                            .attr("class", "concentricchart")
                            .attr("transform", "translate("+((w/3)+padding)+","+h/3+")");

                        methods.radius = Math.min(w, h) / 2;

                        var label_group = chart.append("svg:g")
                            .attr("class", "label_group")
                            .attr("transform", "translate("+((w/3)-15)+","+(-h/4)+")");

                        var legend_group = chart.append("svg:g")
                            .attr("class", "legend_group")
                            .attr("transform", "translate("+((w/3)-130)+","+((-h/4)-5)+")");

                        var value_group = chart.append("svg:g")
                            .attr("class", "value_group")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+(h/4)+")");

                        var path_group = chart.append("svg:g")
                            .attr("class", "path_group")
                            .attr("transform", "translate(0,"+(h/4)+")");               


                        this.generateArcs(selector, data);      
                    },
                    update: function(data){
                        var clone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, data);

                        var preparedData = methods.setData(clone);

                        methods.el = this;
                        methods.animate(preparedData);          
                        methods.oldData = preparedData;
                    },
                    animate: function(data){
                        var that = this;

                        var selector = methods.el["selector"];

                        that.generateArcs(selector, data);
                    },  
                    setData: function(data){
                            var diameter = 2 * Math.PI * this.radius;           
                            var localData = new Array();

                            var segmentValueSum = 0;
                            $.each(data[0].segments, function( ri, va) {
                                segmentValueSum+= va.value;
                            });

                            segmentValueSum = 200;//consistent total accross different data sets

                            $.each(data[0].segments, function(ri, value) {
                                var segmentValue = value.value;

                                var fraction = segmentValue/segmentValueSum;

                                var arcBatchLength = fraction*4*Math.PI;
                                var arcPartition = arcBatchLength;      

                                var startAngle = Math.PI/2;         
                                var endAngle = startAngle + arcPartition; 

                                data[0].segments[ri]["startAngle"] = startAngle;
                                data[0].segments[ri]["endAngle"] = endAngle;
                                data[0].segments[ri]["index"] = ri;
                            });

                            localData.push(data[0].segments);

                            return localData[0];        
                    },
                    textOffset: 10,
                    generateArcs: function(selector, data){
                        var that = this;

                        var chart = d3.select(selector);

                        //append previous value to it.          
                        $.each(data, function(index, value) {
                            if(that.oldData[index] != undefined){
                                data[index]["previousEndAngle"] = that.oldData[index].endAngle;
                            }
                            else{
                                data[index]["previousEndAngle"] = 0;
                            }
                        });     

                        var thickness = $(selector).data("thickness");
                        var ir = ($(selector).data("width")/3);


                        var path_group = d3.select(selector+ ' .path_group');

                        var arcpaths = path_group.selectAll("path")
                            .data(data);

                        arcpaths.enter().append("svg:path")
                            .attr("class", function(d, i){
                                return d.machineType;
                            })  
                            .style("fill", function(d, i){
                                return d.color;
                            })
                            .transition()
                            .ease("elastic")
                            .duration(750)
                            .attrTween("d", function(d){
                                 return that.arcTween(d, thickness, ir);
                            });      

                        arcpaths.transition()
                            .ease("elastic")
                            .style("fill", function(d, i){
                                return d.color;
                            })
                            .duration(750)
                            .attrTween("d", function(d){
                                 return that.arcTween(d, thickness, ir);
                            });      

                        arcpaths.exit().transition()
                            .ease("bounce")
                            .duration(750)
                            .attrTween("d", function(d){
                                 return that.arcTween(d, thickness, ir);
                            })   
                            .remove();

                        //draw labels       
                        that.drawLabels(chart, data, ir, thickness);
                        that.buildLegend(chart, data);
                    },
                    arcTween: function(b, thickness, ir){
                        var that = methods;

                        var prev = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(b));
                        prev.endAngle = b.previousEndAngle;
                        var i = d3.interpolate(prev, b);

                        return function(t) {
                            return that.getArc(thickness, ir)(i(t));
                        };
                    },
                    drawLabels: function(chart, data, ir, thickness){
                        $(methods.el["selector"]+' .value_group').empty();

                        var that = this;

                        var reversedata = data.reverse();
                        var counts = data.length;

                        var value_group = d3.select(methods.el["selector"]+ ' .value_group');

                        valueLabels = value_group.selectAll("text.value").data(reversedata)
                        valueLabels.enter().append("svg:text")
                            .attr("class", "value")
                            .attr("transform", function(d) {       
                                return "translate("+(that.getRadiusRing(ir, counts-1))+", 0)";
                            })
                            .attr("dx", function(d, i){
                                return 20*i;            })
                            .attr("dy", function(d, i){
                                return -5;
                            })
                            .attr("text-anchor", function(d){
                                return "start";
                            }).text(function(d){
                                return d.value;
                            });

                        valueLabels
                            .transition()
                            .duration(300)
                            .attrTween("d", function(d){
                                return that.arcTween(d, thickness, ir);
                            })

                        valueLabels
                            .exit()
                            .remove();      
                    },
                    buildLegend: function(chart, data){
                        console.log("build legend");
                        $(methods.el["selector"]+' .label_group').empty();
                        $(methods.el["selector"]+' .legend_group').empty();


                        var label_group = d3.select(methods.el["selector"]+ ' .label_group');

                        //draw labels                       
                        labels = label_group.selectAll("text.labels")
                            .data(data.reverse());            

                        labels.enter().append("svg:text")
                            .attr("class", "labels")
                            .attr("dy", function(d, i){
                                return 19*i
                            })
                            .attr("text-anchor", function(d){
                                return "start";
                            })
                            .text(function(d){
                                return d.label;
                            });

                        labels.exit().remove();

                        var legend_group = d3.select(methods.el["selector"]+ ' .legend_group');

                        legend = legend_group.selectAll("circle").data(data);

                        legend.enter().append("svg:circle")
                            .attr("cx", 100)
                            .attr("cy", function(d, i){
                                return 19*i
                            })
                            .attr("r", 7)   
                            .attr("width", 18)
                            .attr("height", 18)
                            .style("fill", function(d){
                                return d.color;
                            });

                        legend.exit().remove();
                    },
                    getRadiusRing: function(ir, i){
                        return ir-(i*20);               
                    },
                    getArc: function(thickness, ir){
                        var that = this;

                        var arc = d3.svg.arc()
                            .innerRadius(function(d){
                                return that.getRadiusRing(ir, d.index);                     
                            })
                            .outerRadius(function(d){
                                return that.getRadiusRing(ir+thickness, d.index);   
                            })
                            .startAngle(function(d, i){
                                return d.startAngle;
                            })
                            .endAngle(function(d, i){
                                return d.endAngle;
                            });
                        return arc;
                    },
                    radius: 100,
                    oldData: ""
                };

                $.fn.concentric = function(methodOrOptions) {
                    if ( methods[methodOrOptions] ) {
                        return methods[ methodOrOptions ].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
                    } else if ( typeof methodOrOptions === 'object' || ! methodOrOptions ) {
                        // Default to "init"
                        return methods.init.apply( this, arguments );
                    } else {
                        $.error( 'Method ' +  methodOrOptions + ' does not exist' );
                    }    
                };

            })(jQuery);




            var dataCharts = [
                {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "segments": [
                                {
                                    "label": "Turkey",
                                    "value": 25,
                                    "color": "red"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "United States",
                                    "value": 40,
                                    "color": "blue"                         
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "Switzerland",
                                    "value": 60,
                                    "color": "green"                            
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "Iceland",
                                    "value": 80,
                                    "color": "gold"
                                }                           
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "segments": [
                                {
                                    "label": "Peanut Butter",
                                    "value": 50,
                                    "color": "red"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "Tea",
                                    "value": 25,
                                    "color": "orange"                           
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "Cheese",
                                    "value": 25,
                                    "color": "purple"                           
                                }                       
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                } ,
                {
                    "data": [
                        {
                            "segments": [
                                {
                                    "label": "Jam",
                                    "value": 90,
                                    "color": "purple"
                                },
                                {
                                    "label": "Lemons",
                                    "value": 15,
                                    "color": "brown"                            
                                }                       
                            ]
                        }
                    ]
                }           
            ];

            var clone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, dataCharts);

                //__invoke concentric
                $('[data-role="concentric"]').each(function(index) {
                    var selector = "concetric"+index;

                    $(this).attr("id", selector);

                    var options = {
                        data: clone[0].data,
                        width: $(this).data("width"),
                        height: $(this).data("height")
                    }

                    $("#"+selector).concentric(options);
                });


            $(".testers a").on( "click", function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var clone = jQuery.extend(true, {}, dataCharts);

                var min = 0;
                var max = 2;

                //__invoke concentric
                $('[data-role="concentric"]').each(function(index) {
                    pos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
                    console.log("id", $(this).attr("id"));
                    $("#"+$(this).attr("id")).concentric('update', clone[pos].data);
                });

            }); 

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
    var endAngle = ((ri+1)*arcPartition);
```

by

```
    var endAngle = startAngle + arcPartition;
```

Comment: I've added labels to the rings - however the labels do not appear to be removed on update? http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/114/ - also how do I add the value of the ring at the end of it?

Comment: I've added the values - but again - I have an issue with label placements and label/value removal between updates - http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/115/

Answer (score 1):

[image]

I've made a version where the chart starts from the top - so different orientation. Be good to put this as a variable - maybe have the option to start the chart in 4 different quadrants.

http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/364/

I've adjusted

- the start angle in set Data

  var startAngle = Math.PI*2;

-the label placements

```
valueLabels.enter().append("svg:text")
                            .attr("class", "value")
                            .attr("transform", function(d) {       
                                return "translate("+(that.getRadiusRing(ir, counts-1))+", 0)";
                            })
                            .attr("dx", function(d, i){
                                return 0;
                            })
                            .attr("dy", function(d, i){
                                return (thickness + 4)*i;
                            })
                            .attr("text-anchor", function(d){
                                return "start";
                            }).text(function(d){
                                return d.value;
                            });
```