# pie chart with circular lines

Tags: javascript, charts

Hi Can anyone help me with any links or hints on how I can achieve the following circular line pie chart in javascript (I'm not sure if I'm naming it well).

Thanks in advance.

[image: image for circular line pie chart]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223537/pie-chart-with-jquery

Comment: That is pretty advanced, you might not find that for free. I suggest you go through https://www.google.se/#newwindow=1&q=line+pie+chart+in+javascript and see if you can find something that match your needs.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [d3.js concentric ring chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21779400/d3-js-concentric-ring-chart)